# How to ask German student to homecoming?

Tags: english-to-german, learning

I want to ask one of the foreign German guys to homecoming. I found different quotes but I don't know which one is correct. So how should I write the note to ask him? "Will you go to homecoming with me?"

Comment: Why not in English?

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Because he may be as confused as I was as to what [homecoming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homecoming) is. This does not meen however that it is a good idea to translate the whole sentence.

Comment: dict.cc suggests "Absolvententreffen", but not sure this is really a good match.

Comment: @Em1: I would rather suggest *Absolventenfeier* or *Alumnifest,* as *Absolvententreffen* somewhat implies that this is exclusive to alumni.

Comment: To give context to answerers: "Homecoming" at US high schools is a dance/ball given during the early part of the school year (often just after the school's first football game), and is attended by *current* students, although the phenomenon was originally based around the return of former students. It is not so much a celebration of former students nowadays, but instead a chance for students to socialize with adult supervision.

Comment: @Milchgesicht Das bedeute, dass "Absolvententreffen" und "Ehemaligentreffen" nicht nur eine schlechte, sondern gar falsche Übersetzung ist?! – Eine "Ersties-Party" ist es dann aber auch nicht wirklich?!

Comment: @Em1 ganz genau. Ersties-Party kommt näher ans Ziel, doch Homecoming beschränkt sich nicht nur auf "Freshmen". Mein Vorschlag wäre, wie auch cgoe beantwortete, " Homecoming" nicht zu übersetzen. Der arme Junge müsste auch mal das Wort auf Schildern in der Schule gelesen haben, gell?

Comment: @Milchgesicht Danke für die Erklärung. Das erinnert mich an mein ERSAMUS-Jahr in Frankreich: dort wurde die _rentrée_ gefeiert.

Comment: Ich würde auf den amerikanischen und etwas vagen Begriff homecoming gar nicht eingehen und einfach Schulball/ Schulfeier übersetzen.

Comment: Some of you do not watch enough teen TV shows. I guess this is about an American high school and a German exchange student who would know some English and basics of American high school culture. Of course the answer does not contain enough context.

Comment: @tilinberlin: Can you add "Schultreffen" or better "Schulfest"? Sounds most normal to me.

Answer (score 11):

Since `homecoming` is an expression that has - to my knowledge - no counterpart in German, I would say something like

> Willst du mit mir zum Homecoming gehen?

You could also use

> Hast du Lust, mit mir zum Homecoming zu gehen?

Or, very politely

> Ich würde mich freuen, wenn du mich zum Homecoming begleitest/begleiten würdest.

Update:

I would advice against translating `homecoming`, for the following reasons:

- Since it is attended by current students mostly and all the presented translations somehow imply, that this event is mainly for former students, looking for a German counterpart will most likely confuse the person you want to ask.
- The term `Ehemaligentreffen` sounds rather strange and very formal to me. I would not use it in oral or written German.
- `Homecoming` is - correct me, if I am wrong - an American tradition. To my knowledge, in German speaking countries there are no similar events. Therefore, the German language does not provide a suitable noun for describing the exact event of a `homecoming`. All given translations somehow lack the "core essence", and any German exchange student abroad will understand you perfectly, if you say `homecoming`.

Comment: Not "begleitetest"?

Comment: No, `begleitetest` is the `Präteritum`. Here, we use present tense, although the action will take place in the future.

Comment: Ich denke @CarstenSchultz hat hier eher an Konjunktiv als an Präteritum gedacht. Persönlich würde ich ja "...begleiten würdest." verwenden, vor allen Dingen unter der Betrachtung, dass es die "very politely"-Form ist.

Comment: "no counterpart in German" ? Yes, there is – plenty! Or am I getting "homecoming" completely wrong?

Comment: @Em1 Ist mir auch gerade aufgefallen. `begleitetest` klingt aber, v.a. gesprochen, sehr gewöhnungsbedürftig.

Comment: In my experience, "Ehemaligentreffen" is perfectly fine and not necessarily formal. But it is not anything like "homecoming", either.

Answer (score 4):

- If the *homecoming* you are referring to is with or in honor of alumni, the closest German translation that comes to my mind is **das Ehemaligentreffen**. If you enter *Homecoming* combined with *Ehemaligentreffen* in Google, you'll find some hits where German universities invite to their *Ehemaligentreffen* and also mention the term *homecoming*.
  So for the whole invitation you could write:

  > Willst/Magst du mit mir zum Ehemaligentreffen gehen?
  >   Würdest du mich zum Ehemaligentreffen begleiten?
  >   *(Or any variant that* cgoe *proposed with* Homecoming *substituted by* Ehemaligentreffen.)
- If however alumni don't play a major part in your *homecoming*, I would advice not to translate *homecoming* at all. Remember that, when treating it like a German noun, you should capitalize the first letter: *das Homecoming*.

Comment: Since American high school "homecomings" no longer have much of anything to do with "returning alumni", Ehemaligentreffen is more suited for a " high school reunion", which is typically held 10, 20, 50 years after a cohort has graduated.

Comment: @Milchgesicht: I've never been to a homecoming and the only information I have about it is the Wikipedia article linked somewhere in the comments. What Wikipedia describes sounds like an _Ehemaligentreffen_ to me, since in almost every paragraph there's the word "alumni" present. (However, I cannot imagine a German _Ehemaligentreffen_ with football/sports matches, coronation of a queen/king and so on; but that seems to be an America-vs.-Europe thing :-)).

Comment: I certainly understand, and due to the history of the term, it is a hard one to translate (historical meaning vs. current use, which is only tenuously related). Still as a US American who went to a homecoming dance years ago, I dont think our hypothetical German exchange student will stand much of a chance and understanding the note if OP uses *Ehemaligentreffen*. It is however certainly a perfect translation for "reunion" in the sense of a meeting of alumni.

Answer (score 4):

- In casual speech I would also consider "***Ehemaligentreffen***" ("*formers' gathering*") the correct term – if you relate to people you were studying with. This type of event can either be an official gathering of students, invited by their university – or an inofficial at some bar – or everything inbetween.
- The rather formal term "***Alumnitreffen***" ("*alumni gathering*") is probably what institutions inviting former students would write on the invitation – if they try to be make a formal impression. And as far as I know the term suggests that you actually gratuated from that institution.
- Then there is also the term "***Graduiertentreffen***" ("*graduates' gathering*") which is also rather formal – and used for gatherings of graduates only.
- And then again former school (high school) mates celebrate their parties usually under the label "***Klassentreffen***" ("*class gathering*").

But since I've never been to a *real* ***homecoming*** I actually can't say which term would be closest.